# Docker Couchbase: Cannot connect to port 8091 using curl from within entrypoint script

Tags: docker, couchbase, boot2docker, docker-machine

Running `docker-machine` version 0.5.0, `Docker` version 1.9.0 on OS X 10.11.1.

I've a [Couchbase image](https://github.com/abhijitsarkar/docker/tree/master/couchbase4) of my own (not the official one). From inside the [entrypoint script](https://github.com/abhijitsarkar/docker/blob/master/couchbase4/init.sh), I'm running some `curl` commands to configure the Couchbase server and to load sample data. Problem is, `curl` fails with error message `Failed to connect to localhost port 8091: Connection refused`. 
I've tried `127.0.0.1`, `0.0.0.0`, `localhost`, all without any success. `netstat` shows that port `8091` on `localhost` is listening. If I later log on to the server using `docker exec` and run the same `curl` commands, those work! What am I missing?

Error:

```
couchbase4 |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
couchbase4 |                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8091: Connection refused
```

netstat output:

```
root@cd4d3eb00666:/opt/couchbase/var/lib# netstat -lntu                              
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21100           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21101           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9998          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4369            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8091            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8092            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41125           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11209           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11210           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::11209                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::11210                :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: Could you please post your entrypoint script?

Comment: @ReneM. Already there. The text 'entrypoint script' is a hyperlink.

Comment: Wait a second! Your entrypoint script should start couchdb, So when your curl command failes in there but later works. I think you should think about the order of your commands in the entrypoint script. First start couchdb before you try to connect to it with curl ;)

Comment: @ReneM. You missed the very 1st line of the script?
`$CB_HOME/etc/couchbase_init.d restart`

Comment: You are running full linux with initd and stuff like that in your container? Why? Look up the official images, only run what needed, run your services by hand over your entrypoint script. Thats my advice

Comment: You problem is for sure how your linux init system is starting the services and in which point of the starting process docker runs your entrypoint script. I would rewind and restart with a clean image, that is only running couchdb and installs curl. Where couchdb is started over your entrypoint script.

Comment: Not running full image and no `init.d` is involved. If you look, `$CB_HOME/etc/couchbase_init.d` is not a standard `init.d` script, because it's not located in `/etc/init.d` It's just a script that Couchbase creates. FYI, on a full distro, it's ran by an `init.d` script called `couchbase-server`.

May I ask that you are willing to help, you look at the code first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if I do the `curl`s after restarting the server, those work. Go figure! That said, note that the REST API for installing sample buckets is undocumented as far as I know. `arun-gupta`'s blog and his answer here are the only places where I saw any mention of a REST call for installing sample buckets. There's a [python script](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/settings/install-sample-buckets.html) available but that requires installing `python-httplib2`.

That said, `arun-gupta`'s last `curl` statement may be improved upon as follows:

```
if [ -n "$SAMPLE_BUCKETS" ]; then
    IFS=',' read -ra BUCKETS <<< "$SAMPLE_BUCKETS"

    for bucket in "${BUCKETS[@]}"; do
        printf "\n[INFO] Installing %s.\n" "$bucket"
        curl -sSL -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n" -u $CB_USERNAME:$CB_PASSWORD --data-ascii '["'"$bucket"'"]' $ENDPOINT/sampleBuckets/install
    done
fi
```

where `SAMPLE_BUCKETS` can be a comma-separated environment variable, possible values being combinations of  `gamesim-sample`, `beer-sample` and `travel-sample`. The `--data-ascii` option keeps `curl` from choking on the dynamically created JSON.

Now if only there was an easy way to start the server in the foreground. :)

Comment: Have you looked at the server that starts the server in background, invokes the REST API, and then brings it back in the foreground?

    set -m

    /entrypoint.sh couchbase-server &

    sleep 10

   Invoke REST API

   fg 1

Complete script at: https://github.com/arun-gupta/docker-images/blob/master/couchbase/configure-cluster.sh

Comment: Invoking `couchbase-server` directly gives me a bunch of errors. There're differences among the base images and dependencies between your image and what I've. But I'll try `fg 1`.

Comment: I'm using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org) to control the processes. `fg 1` didn't work but `$CB_HOME/etc/couchbase_init.d restart && fg` did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: `fg 1` requires to enable job control.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM couchbase

COPY configure-cluster.sh /opt/couchbase

CMD ["/opt/couchbase/configure-cluster.sh"]
```

and `configure-cluster.sh`

```
/entrypoint.sh couchbase-server &

sleep 10

curl -v -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default -d memoryQuota=300 -d indexMemoryQuota=300
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8091/node/controller/setupServices -d services=kv%2Cn1ql%2Cindex
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8091/settings/web -d port=8091 -d username=Administrator -d password=password
curl -v -u Administrator:password -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8091/sampleBuckets/install -d '["travel-sample"]'
```

This configures the Couchbase server but still debugging how to bring Couchbase back in foreground.

Complete details at: https://github.com/arun-gupta/docker-images/tree/master/couchbase

Comment: The only noticeable differences I see is that you're building from the official image and sleeping longer. The reason I built my own is that the official image is based on Ubuntu (mine on Debian) and installs a bunch of packages I don't yet need. I'll increase the sleep time and see what happens.

Comment: I figured it out and posted an answer. From what I saw, running the server in foreground requires a lot of duplication of code from `$CB_HOME/etc/couchbase_init.d`. I've given up on that and just tailing a `here` doc at the the end now.